# Node.js: HTTP/REST requests using existing libraries over proprietary transport protocol

Tags: node.js, http

Given a standard Node.js HTTP library, or an existing REST client library, what would be the most feasible way to allow such a library to perform those HTTP requests over the top of my own protocol?

To put this another way: I aim provide a module which *looks* like a HTTP client. It accepts HTTP requests headers, and returns HTTP responses. What options should I consider to adapt an existing REST library to work with my 'pseudo' HTTP client module, as opposed to the standard Node library HTTP client?

**Further background information**

I wish to create a server application (based on Node.js) which makes HTTP REST requests to a remote embedded device. However, due to NAT, it is not possible for the application server to make client TCP connections directly to the remote device. Therefore, to get around NAT, I will devise my own proprietary protocol which involves the remote device initiating a persistent connection to the application server. Then, once that persistent connection is established, the Node.js application shall be able to make HTTP requests back over that persistent connection to the networked device.

My objective is therefore to create a Node.js module which acts as a 'bridge' layer between incoming socket connections from the networked devices, and the main application which makes REST requests. The aim is that the application would make REST requests as if it were making HTTP client requests to a server, when in fact the HTTP requests and responses are being conveyed on top of the proprietary protocol.

An option I'm presently considering is for my 'bridge' module to implement an interface that mimics that of `http.request(options,[callback])` and somehow enforce a REST client library to use this interface instead of the Node HTTP client. Supposedly at minimum I'd have to lightly modify whichever REST client library I'd use to achieve this.

As explained above, I'm essentially trying to create my own form of NAT traversal using an intermediary server. The intermediary server would provide the front-end UI to users, and make back-end data requests to the embedded networked devices. Connections between embedded devices and application server would be persistent, and initiated from the embedded devices, to avoid the usual NAT headaches (i.e. the requirement to configure port forwarding).

Though I mentioned earlier I'd achieve the device-to-server connection using my own protocol over a raw socket connection, the mechanism I'm actually experimenting with right now is to use plain HTTP together with long-polling. The embedded device initiates a HTTP connection to the application server and delayed responses are used to convey data back to the device when the server has something to send. I would then 'tunnel' HTTP requests going in the reverse direction over the top of this.

Therefore, in simple terms, my 'bridge' layer is something that accepts HTTP connections inwards from both sides (outside device connections, and inside web application REST requests). By using long-polling it would effectively convey requests and responses between the connected clients.

Comment: Downvoter: Give me some actual feedback here please by leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the http layer, create a man-in-the-middle. Create an http server in node that is the target for all of the rest requests. It then transfers the request onto the proprietary protocol and handles the response by translating back to rest.

This way you don't have to hack the rest code and can even swap it out for another library if needed.

Comment: Ah. So in other words, as well as the 'public' server for outside connections, I have an internal server instance (listening I presume on some non-publicly accessible port) to accept the REST requests. Then, I simply point my REST library to make requests on localhost. I feel very, very silly now for thinking about this too hard.